# Convert varchar value to datetime in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

In my import table I have the following column defined:

```
LFZ_begin VARCHAR(50) NULL
```

Now when I try to define the column in a view as `DATETIME` and call the view in SSMS, I get the following error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

In my view the column is defined as follows:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DATETIME, LFZ_begin, 120)) AS LFZ_begin,
```

I need to expect the result value like that: `2020-09-04 00:00:0000`

Does anyone have an idea for this issue?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings to begin with. Use the correct date type eg `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`. Everything else is just coverups. Fix the real bug

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012R2** - just **2012** - and why are you mentioning SQL Server 2012 in the title, but 2014 in the tags?? Please be consistent and precise about your environment!

Comment: BTW we can't tell why the conversion failed without knowing what the text looks like. If you fix the bug though, you won't have to worry about formats. Dates have no format, they are binary types

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model and *never* store date/time values as strings.  In the meantime you can fix the view using `try_` functions:

```
TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, LFZ_begin, 120)) AS LFZ_begin,
```

Note:  This will eliminate the error on invalid formatted columns.  Whether it ever returns a valid value depends on the data -- and you have shown no sample data so there is no way to suggest a solution to whatever the underlying problem is.